# Is there a vectorized way to sample multiples times with np.random.choice() with differents p?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to implement a variation ratio, and I need `T` samples from an array `C`, but each sample has different weights `p_t`.

I'm using this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

batch_size = 1
T = 3
C = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])
# p_batch_T dimensions: (batch, sample, class)
p_batch_T = np.array([[[0.01, 0.98, 0.01],
                       [0.3,  0.15, 0.55],
                       [0.85, 0.1,  0.05]]])

def variation_ratio(C, p_T):
  # This function works only with one sample from the batch.
  Y_T = np.array([np.random.choice(C, size=1, p=p_t) for p_t in p_T]) # vectorize this
  C_mode, frecuency =  stats.mode(Y_T)
  T = len(Y_T)
  return 1.0 - (f/T)

def variation_ratio_batch(C, p_batch_T):
  return np.array([variation_ratio(C, p_T) for p_T in p_batch_T]) # and vectorize this
```

Is there a way to implement these functions with any for?

Comment: Do you want to sampling T samples (e.g., A, B, C, A, A, ...) based on the given probabilities (e.g., [0.01, 0.98, 0.01], [0.3,  0.15, 0.55], ...)?

Comment: I want to sample `T` samples from `C`, but each sampling has a different probability `p_t` for `C`. As you can see in my code, I can do it already, first iterating for each row in the batch, then for each probability. I need to do it without iterating so over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stead of sampling with the given distribution `p_T`, we can sample uniformly between `[0,1]` and compare that to the cumulative distribution:

Let's start with `Y_T`, say for `p_T = p_batch_T[0]`

```
cum_dist = p_batch_T.cumsum(axis=-1)

idx_T = (np.random.rand(len(C),1) < cum_dist[0]).argmax(-1)
Y_T = C[idx_T[...,None]]
_, f = stats.mode(Y_T) # here axis=0 is default
```

Now let take that to the `variation_ratio_batch`:

```
idx_T = (np.random.rand(len(p_batch_T), len(C),1) < cum_dist).argmax(-1)

Y = C[idx_T[...,None]]

f = stats.mode(Y, axis=1)   # notice axis 0 is batch

out = 1 - (f/T)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Just a little change in the shape of `np.random.rand`, this should be `(p_batch_T.shape[0],p_batch_T.shape[1],1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

First, create a 2D weights array of shape `(T, len(C))` and take the cumulative sum:

```py
n_rows = 5
n_cols = 3

weights = np.random.rand(n_rows, n_cols) 
cum_weights = (weights / weights.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)).cumsum(axis=1)
```

`cum_weights` might look like this:

```py
array([[0.09048919, 0.58962127, 1.        ],
       [0.36333997, 0.58380885, 1.        ],
       [0.28761923, 0.63413879, 1.        ],
       [0.39446498, 0.98760834, 1.        ],
       [0.27862476, 0.79715149, 1.        ]])
```

Next, we can compare `cum_weights` to the appropriately sized output of `np.random.rand`. By taking `argmin`, we find the index in each row where the random number generated is greater than the cumulative weight:

```py
indices = (cum_weights < np.random.rand(n_rows, 1)).argmin(axis=1)
```

We can then use `indices` to index an array of values of shape `(n_cols,)`, which is `len(C)` in your original example.

Comment: Almost identical to my approach. One thing is that `np.random.rand(...)` is always `<=1` so `indices` is never `2` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of Quang's and gmds' solutions:

```
def sample(ws, k):
    """Weighted sample k elements along the last axis.
    ws -- Tensor of probabilities, shape (*, n)
    k  -- Number of elements to sample.
    Returns tensor of shape (*, k) with values in {0, ..., n-1}.
    """
    assert np.allclose(ws.sum(-1), 1)
    cs = ws.cumsum(-1)
    ps = np.random.random(ws.shape[:-1] + (k,))
    return (cs[..., None, :] < ps[..., None]).sum(-1)
```

Say we have some stuff

```
>>> stuff = array([[0, 1, 2],
                   [3, 4, 5],
                   [6, 7, 8]])
```

And some weights / sampling probabilities.

```
>>> ws = array([[0.41296038, 0.36070229, 0.22633733],
                [0.37576672, 0.14518771, 0.47904557],
                [0.14742326, 0.29182459, 0.56075215]])
```

And we want to sample 2 elements along each row. Then we do

```
>>> ids = sample(ws, 2)
[[2, 0],
 [1, 2],
 [2, 2]]
```

And we can retrieve the sampled values from `stuff` using `np.take_along_axis`:

```
>>> np.take_along_axis(stuff, ids)
[[2, 0],
 [4, 5],
 [8, 8]]
```

The code could be generalized to sampling along an axis other than the last one, but I got confused about broadcasting, so somebody else should have a stab at it!

Answer (score -1):

`np.vectorize` should work:

```
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

@partial(np.vectorize, excluded=['rng'], signature='(),(k)->()')
def choice_batched(rng, probs):
  return rng.choice(a=probs.shape[-1], p=probs)
```

then

```
num_classes = 3
batch_size = 5
alpha = .5  # Dirichlet prior hyperparameter.

rng = np.random.default_rng()

probs = np.random.dirichlet(alpha=np.full(fill_value=alpha, shape=num_classes), size=batch_size)
# Check each row sums to 1.
assert np.allclose(probs.sum(axis=-1), 1)

print(choice_batched(rng, probs))
print(choice_batched(rng, probs))
print(choice_batched(rng, probs))
print(choice_batched(rng, probs))
```

gives

```
[2 0 0 0 1]
[1 0 0 0 1]
[2 0 2 0 1]
[1 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Unfortunately `vectorize` doesn't actually make your code any faster.

Comment: That is indeed a shame but speed isn't everything. Do you think it makes it more readable?

Comment: vectorization is about speed; `np.vectorize` insinuates speed while actually being slower. It's also less readable; your `choice_batched` is way less readable than a list comprehension.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by these comments. The original question wasn't about speed, it asks for a vectorised solution. I didn't claim it was faster.